# Run admin/management tasks as one-off processes in the JVM (12 factor app)

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, 12factor

Can someone please provide an example of running admin/management tasks as one-off processes (as propounded in the twelfth factor of the 12 factor app manifesto) bearing in mind it would be in the context of a JVM app relying on the Gradle buildpack and running on Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy.

In your codebase, build a script that can be run using some command-line invocation.

For instance:

`java myscript`

Once you've verified this works locally, push your code to Heroku, open up the scheduler addon via `$ heroku addons:open scheduler`, then define how often you want the task to run, and in the command box put in your command to run it: `java myscript`

All Heroku will do is run a dyno and run that command you specify. Super basic!